# Error in implementing router

Tags: node.js, express

Here is my code.

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    log = require('./libs/log')(module),
    api = require('./libs/api.js'),
    app = express();

// settings
app.set('port', 5000);

// to process post requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// routes
rawQuestionRouter = require('./routes/rawQuestionRoutes.js');
app.use('/rawQuestions', rawQuestionRouter);
```

and routes/rawQuestionRoute.js:

```
var express = require('express');

var routes = function() {
  var rawQuestionRouter = express.Router();

  rawQuestionRouter.route('/test')
    .post(function(request, response) {
      log.debug(request.body);
      response.send('raw question saved');
    });

    return rawQuestionRouter;
}

module.exports = routes;
```

**Update:**

When I make a POST request on '/rawQuestions/test' the server don't respond. Why?

Comment: `module.export` - should be `exports`?

Comment: thanks. it was a reason of error

Comment: I have fixed it, but server don't respond for this URL

Comment: Try `rawQuestionRouter.post("/test", function() {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exporting the `routes` function, which is not a router (it *returns* one, but that's not the same).

There are several solutions:

```
// server.js
app.use('/rawQuestions', rawQuestionRouter());
```

Or:

```
// routes/rawQuestionRoute.js
module.exports = routes();
```

Or just remove the entire `routes` function altogether and export the router instance directly.